# Is there a combination of takeWhile,dropWhile in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, split, standard-library

In Scala, I want to split a string at a specific character like so:

```
scala> val s = "abba.aadd" 
s: String = abba.aadd
scala> val (beforeDot,afterDot) = (s takeWhile (_!='.'), s dropWhile (_!='.'))
beforeDot: String = abba
afterDot: String = .aadd
```

This solution is slightly inefficient (maybe not asymptotically), but I have the feeling something like this might exist in the standard library already. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldnt there be a `split` function? that would be cleaner. Or is keeping the `.` important?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is a `span` method:

```
scala> val (beforeDot, afterDot) = s.span{ _ != '.' }
beforeDot: String = abba
afterDot: String = .aadd
```

From the [Scala documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.html#span(pred:A=>Boolean):(Repr,Repr)):

> `c span p` is equivalent to (but possibly more efficient than) `(c takeWhile p, c dropWhile p)`, provided the evaluation of the predicate p does not cause any side-effects.

Comment: Well, I can't possibly ask for anything closer to my question :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `splitAt` for what you want:

```
val s = "abba.aadd"
val (before, after) = s.splitAt(s.indexOf('.'))
```

Output:

```
before: String = abba
after: String = .aadd
```

Comment: Traverses the sequence twice, though

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends on the Scala optimiser.

Comment: I think it is worthwhile to mention that accessing indices of sequences should probably be avoided if possible, the reason being that random access is prone to one-off errors and rarely lends itself to composition within functional programming (this is based on my experience).
Where random access comes into play is often in performance optimizations where arrays are often the target datastructure.

Comment: `splitAt` is for `take` and `drop`, `span` is for `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`.